# I am getting zero validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am getting zero validation accuracy on my LSTM model.
As my model is a many to one model, I am using one unit in the last dense layer. But, it is giving me this accuracy.

> 536/536 [==============================] - 6s 8ms/step - loss: nan -
> accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
> <keras.callbacks.History at 0x7efd6b9bc5d0>

My model is:

```
classifier1 = Sequential()
classifier1.add(CuDNNLSTM(100, input_shape = (x1_train.shape[1], x1_train.shape[2]), return_sequences= True))
# classifier1.add(Dropout(0.02))
classifier1.add(CuDNNLSTM(100))
classifier1.add(Dropout(0.02))
classifier1.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# classifier1.add(Dense(300))
classifier1.add(Dropout(0.02))
classifier1.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
# classifier1.add(Dropout(0.02))
# classifier1.add(Dense(1))
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=3, verbose = 1)
callback = [early_stopping]

classifier1.compile(
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
# loss = 'mean_squared_error',
# optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.05, decay= 1e-6),
optimizer='rmsprop', 
metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier1.fit(x1_train, y1_train, epochs=1 ,
              validation_data=(x1_test, y1_test),
              batch_size=50
              # class_weight= 'balanced'
              # callbacks = callback)
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You cannot use softmax with only one neuron (think about what values it can produce).

Answer (score 0):

The output of your network is of dimension 1, so you should use in the last layer a sigmoid activation instead of a softmax and especially replace the categorical cross entropy by a binary cross entropy, because it is a two class problem. Then it should work.